# How to call a method (arduino) from an existing Class from my Custom class?

Tags: c++, arduino

So I have a custom class for the Arduino that I need to get the time from the ubiquitous Time.h http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/time#.UxNa6_1dLoo class.

Device.cpp

```
#include <Time.h> 
void Device::checkTimedEvent() {
    if(hour() == hour[timedIndex]) {
      Serial.println("TIME!!!!!: ");
    }
}
```

error

> error: '((Device*)this)->Device::hour' cannot be used as a function

How do I expose hour() so Device.cpp can use it? Do I need to make an instance of Time or something?
thanks

Comment: Whats / Wheres the definition of hour?

Comment: A common library used for arduino http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/time#.UxNa6_1dLoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Device` has a member variable named `hour` which takes precedence during name lookup. You need to use the scope operator to instruct the compiler to explicitly use the global function named `hour`.

```
#include <Time.h> 
void Device::checkTimedEvent() {
    if(::hour() == hour[timedIndex]) {
    // ^^ fully qualified name using scope operator 
        Serial.println("TIME!!!!!: ");
    }
}
```